# Visualizing Air Flow: Arrows change color

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation

I'm making a airflow simulation video for some machine. So far I have made the machine, and a long array of arrows. I intend to make these follow a curve path and animate them along it.

Question: How can I change the color of the arrows on a specific point on the curve (when the air becomes hot)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a conventional *Array* and *Curve* modifier approach, you can pick up the (0-1) U of the curve your array is on, using a Geometry Nodes group:

[image]

.. and then pick up the stored attribute in a shader:

[image]

.. which can vary the color of your array along the curve's length:

[image]

[image]
(Blender 3.41 stable)

However, there might be an argument for modelling the heat distribution on a sampled volume, other mesh components, or 'Hot' Empties, and picking up colour from those, for a more flexible workflow? All of those would be possible using Geometry Nodes, or vertex-groups and a *Vertex Proximity* modifier

Comment: Hello @RobinBetts ! thanks for you thorough explanation! I will try this out asap!
I suspect (with my limited knowledge) that i use a conventional array and curve approach. 
For now I will give this a shot and see if it suffice - or i might comment again with another question :)

Answer (score -2):

You can use a color gradient fill to gradually change the color of the arrows as they move along the curve. You can also add a color filter to the arrows at the point on the curve where you want them to change color.

Comment: Hey Roshin. Thanks for your answer! Ill give it a look :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.